# Filter twice with MAX() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-max

I have the following table called `my_values` in a `MySQL 5.7` database:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 7 | something4 |
| foo | 5 | something1 |
| foo | 12 | anything5 |
| bar | 3 | something7 |
| bar | 18 | anything5 |
| bar | 0 | anything8 |
| baz | 99 | anything9 |
| baz | 100 | something0 |

As you see, there are duplicates in `value1`. I want to `SELECT` each unique `value1` only once, but that row with the highest value in `value2`.

I'm using this query for that:

```
SELECT v.* FROM my_values v WHERE v.value2 = (SELECT MAX(v2.value2) FROM my_values v2 WHERE v2.value1 = v.value1);
```

The result is:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 12 | anything5 |
| bar | 18 | anything5 |
| baz | 100 | something0 |

[Here's a fiddle of that.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vLkucGU824gn2XVpcAPzv1/7)

From this result I want to `SELECT` each unique `value3` only once, but that row with the highest value in `value2` (no matter what `value1` is).

So expected result would be:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bar | 18 | anything5 |
| baz | 100 | something0 |

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it :

```
select t1.*
from my_values t1
natural join (select value1, MAX(value2) value2
               from my_values 
               group by value1 ) t2
natural join (select value3, MAX(value2) value2
               from my_values 
               group by value3) t3
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vLkucGU824gn2XVpcAPzv1/10)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples for the comparison:

```
select t.*
from my_values t
where (t.value2, t.value3) = (select t2.value2, t2.value3
                              from my_values t2
                              where t2.value1 = t.value1
                              order by t2.value2 desc, t2.value3 desc
                              limit 1
                             );
```

Comment: `my_values` is missing in your query.

Comment: the sub query will return more than one record , does this really work ? I think you need limit 1